# Joining trees together to create a new tree - Coq

Tags: coq

I am trying to create a new counter-model given a list of previous counter models. These models are structured like trees.
Currently, I am looking at the reachability relation only.
Example:
For a model with root world w and reachability relation R,
let new_R := R U (u,w)
This creates a new model with root world u and reachability relation new_R.

To create the reachability relation, I have described a function which says:
Any two worlds u,w;  (u,w) in new_R if:

1. IF u is the new_root THEN w must be the root of a successor model. AND
2. IF w is the new_root THEN u must be the root of a predeccessor model. AND
3. IF (u!=root and w!=root) THEN exists R in the list of models such that (R u w).
   I have attempted to code it as follows:

```coq
Definition join_rel (world : Type)
  (ws_bac : list(world)) (rs_bac : list(world -> world -> Prop))
  (ws_fwd : list(world)) (rs_fwd : list(world -> world -> Prop))
  (w : world) : world -> world -> Prop :=
(fun w1 w2 => (w1 = w -> In w2 ws_fwd) /\
              (w2 = w -> In w1 ws_bac) /\
              ((~w1 = w /\ ~w2 = w) ->
               (exists w' r',  (* <w,R> *)
                 (In (w',r') (combine (ws_fwd++ws_bac) (rs_fwd ++ rs_bac)) /\
                  reachable r' w1 w' /\ reachable r' w2 w' /\ r' w1 w2)))).
```

Basically, the first clause is connecting my new root to all the models which must be successors. The second clause is connecting my new root to all the predecessors.
The third clause is copying over information from the previous models. This clause is creating problems for me and I believe this formalization is too simple.

Let R_new be the new relation we get from taking the union as described above. Let R1 be the relation for a model M1 with root w1. I want to prove that:
Forall worlds (w) in M1, If R_new w w1 then R1 w w1.

The reason the proof should go through is the following:

1. Since w in M1, therefore w is not the new_root. Since w1 is a root another model therefore w1 is not the new_root. So, we are looking at clause 3.
2. There exists an R such that R w w1. Since w is in M1, R must be R1.
3. Therefore R1 w w1.

However my current approach is too weak to prove this. I am having trouble with point 2.
Does someone know how to formalise this? Coq complains that R does not have to be R1 necessarily. My current idea is to make each individual R use an individual type, so that `R1 : world1 -> world1 -> Prop`; `R2 : world2 -> world2 -> Prop` etc.
However, then I am struggling to write the join function as I do not know where to even begin with this approach.

Any advice would be helpful. I am a Coq newcomer so links where I can read up on similar problems would be great as well.

Comment: I think your argument should not be too difficult to formalize, but right now we are lacking some details to be able to help you. Could you include a self-contained Coq snippet with the main definitions of your development, and also the theorem statement that you would like to prove?